# Launch .desktop file from bash script and await exit

Tags: command-line, bash, gtk

I need to execute a *.desktop* file with a java version different from what I usually use. To do that, I decided to write a bash script that uses `update-alternatives` to set the java version to the required one, start the application and to reset the java version after the application has been exited.

I use `gtk-launch` to launch the application, but it does not wait for it to exit. Thus the java version reset takes place too early.

I need a way to wait for the app to exit before resuming code. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below, in a bash script:
`command2` is executed only if `command1` returns an exit status of zero.

```
command1 && command2
```